# If expressions in windows workflow?

Tags: .net, vb.net, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

In an windows workflow i written the following if expression.

```
If(Type = "true", String.Format("AName {0}",app.Name), String.Format("DName {0}",app.Name)
```

In above condition if type is true first string AName will display else displaying the DName.
we are using windows workflow 4.0 ,the above condition working fine in my server,but not working in client machines.please let me know any gueses on this issue happens.

Please tell me anything wrong in above if expression code....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How does `Type = "true"` work, ever?

The System.Type class represents the program's metadata.  I don't think it can ever equal True